# CSS trick to display several UL lists with LI elements in multiple columns, depending on the webpage width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

For an HTML game website I display several UL lists at the bottom of every page:

```
<h2>How to play?</h2>

<ul>
    <li><a href="/en/ws/google">Via Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="/en/ws/apple">Via Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="/en/ws/facebook">Via Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="/en/ws/amazon">Via Amazon</a></li>
    <li><a href="/en/ws/huawei">Via Huawei</a></li>
</ul>
```

Currently the lists are just displayed one above the other:

[image: screenshot]

In some Wordpress themes I can see that the lists are displayed near each other when the webpage is wide enough:

[image: screenshot 2]

Could someone please recommend a CSS trick for doing it?

It is difficult to understand how Wordpress is doing it and I have also tried searching, but the keywords are too common to find good pointers for my problem.

**UPDATE:**

I have followed the now deleted (why?) suggestion by Majicman02 (thank you!) and have tried using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
#footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
    <h2>How to play?</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="/en/ws/google">Via Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/ws/apple">Via Apple</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/ws/facebook">Via Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/ws/amazon">Via Amazon</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/ws/huawei">Via Huawei</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Mobile game version</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="/en/ws/android">For Android</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/ws/ios">For iOS</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Where to talk?</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://facebook.com/groups/12345/">At Facebook</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Other languages</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="/de/ws">My word game (German)</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ru/ws">My word game (Russian)</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Legal documents</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="/en/ws/tos">Terms of service</a></li>
        <li><a href="/en/ws/privacy">Privacy policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="/de/ws/imprint">Impressum</a></li>
        <li><a href="/de/ws/dsgvo">Datenschutzerkl&auml;rung</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the result looks good in the sense that the full webpage width is used.

But how to keep the h2-header above the ul-lists please?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This goes down to styling. Where's your CSS at?

Comment: I don't have any CSS for the footer yet. I am in a process of migrating my HTML game from being wrapped in a Wordpress website to a website generated completely by my game servlet and I wonder how to have a simple but multi-columned footer with several UL lists.

Comment: inspect the code of that wordpress site and you have your answer

Comment: Maybe you want something link column-count? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp

Comment: You mean CSS media queries?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber - Maybe you can start with this article - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

You can easily align sections using CSS grids. If you are stuck anywhere, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have got my multi-columned webpage footer working by using [flex-wrap](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) property of flexbox.

Also, I had to wrap my H2-headers and UL-lists by a DIV to prevent them from breaking apart:

```css
#footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#footer > div {
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
    <div>
        <h2>How to play?</h2>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="/en/ws/google">Via Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="/en/ws/apple">Via Apple</a></li>
            <li><a href="/en/ws/facebook">Via Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="/en/ws/amazon">Via Amazon</a></li>
            <li><a href="/en/ws/huawei">Via Huawei</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Mobile game version</h2>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="/en/ws/android">For Android</a></li>
            <li><a href="/en/ws/ios">For iOS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Where to talk?</h2>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://facebook.com/groups/12345/">At Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Other languages</h2>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="/de/ws">My word game (German)</a></li>
            <li><a href="/ru/ws">My word game (Russian)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Legal documents</h2>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="/en/ws/tos">Terms of service</a></li>
            <li><a href="/en/ws/privacy">Privacy policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="/de/ws/imprint">Impressum</a></li>
            <li><a href="/de/ws/dsgvo">Datenschutzerkl&auml;rung</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I have added some padding around those `#footer` [children DIV elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).